# Can’t connect to local PostgresSQL server

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x, rails

I have the [Postres app](http://postgresapp.com) installed an running on my Mac. And it has worked beautifully. I don’t know what changed, but now I cannot connect to it from Rails, PG Commander, PG Admin or the command `psql -h localhost`. However, I can connect with just `psql`. I get the following error in the log as soon as the connection times out:

```
LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

Rails database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_db
  host: localhost
```

PG Commander settings:

[image]

pg_hba.conf:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

postgresql.conf: https://gist.github.com/davbeck/49a23a48fa161b3e06fc#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: [Check the settings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) in `pg_hba.conf` which can be found in the data dir. My guess is you allow ip4 and deny ip6 or vice versa. Adjusting log settings in `postgresql.conf` may also prove informative.

Comment: I updated the question with those 2 files. It would appear that both ipv4 and 6 are enabled. I haven’t touched any config files though.

Comment: The message starting with LOG doesn't mean there is an error.  Still, you can have a look [here](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Incomplete-startup-packet-help-needed-td5199030.html) for some clues.  Are there any other messages (LOG or FATAL) around in the log?

Comment: Yes, I know. I’ve seen tons of responses noting that certain services can cause that message to appear. However, it is not happening at regular intervals, only when a connection finally times out. And it is the only message, so it is all I have to go on.

Comment: You may want to check your firewall settings. Then in postgresql.conf try setting `log_connections=on` and `log_min_messages=debug1` and see what shows up in the logs. Increase log_min_messages up to debug5 if that isn't helpful.

Comment: Here is log level debug5: https://gist.github.com/davbeck/4908ad02f0ce90664dcf

Answer (score 0):

Since your local psql session just works, your database is OK. Your other sessions try to connect using network. Things to check here are the listen_addresses and port parameters to be found in your postgres.conf They must match with what the clients specify.

Next to that, your firewalls must allow the access. For your local firewall check your settings Security and Privacy settings. There is a good chance that there is a question asking to allow your postmaster to connect to the network.